# Cannot query for chrome's bookmarks when it is close

Tags: java, android, database, google-chrome, bookmarks

In my android app, the user supposes to search for bookmarks in chrome browser.
But I found once I turn off the browser, the query will get a "null" cursor.(Works fine when chrome running in the background)
Here is my code:(query for all bookmarks)

```
resultCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, new String[] {Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL}, null, null, sortOrder);
```

There is no permission warning in the Log.

I tried to replace the content provider uri to `"content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks"` and get the same problem.
I wonder if there is something wrong in the query code, or it is just a bug at chrome side.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a Chrome issue. 
Reference: [code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=497538](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=497538)